# Requests to docker containers failing on chrome for OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, docker, docker-for-mac

I have several docker containers running on OSX using Docker for Mac and I've set up port mapping in the docker-compose file in order to access them on localhost. This usually works, but sometimes the requests fail when accessing them from the Chrome browser.

In this event I see nothing in the docker-compose output suggesting that the container has received a request, and the tab just hangs for however long I leave it. The only thing that helps is waiting a few moments and then opening another url (or even the same localhost url) in a different Chrome tab, this sometimes causes the request to localhost to go through.

I'm having no problem with other browsers (Firefox, Safari) and the same containers can be accessed reliably with Chrome on Ubuntu.

Versions:

- OSX: 10.12.4
- Docker: 17.03.1-ce-mac12
- Chrome: 58.0.3029.110